# Reactive android database migration if only new table is added

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, reactive

I Am added the new coulmn for database ,I am getting this error while running program with ReActive android Database.

Unable to create application com.reactiveandroid.sample.App: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SQL file assets/from_2_to_3.sql note found.

```
@Database(name = "AppDatabase", version = 3)
public class AppDatabase {
    static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2=new Migration(1,2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            AssetsSqlMigration.executeSqlScript(database,"assets/from_1_to_2.sql");
        }
    };

    static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3=new Migration(2,3) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            AssetsSqlMigration.executeSqlScript(database,"assets/from_2_to_3.sql");
        }
    };
}
```

---

public class App extends Application{

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    DatabaseConfig appDatabaseConfig = new DatabaseConfig.Builder(AppDatabase.class)
            .addModelClasses(Note.class, Folder.class, NoteFolderRelation.class)
            .addMigrations(AppDatabase.MIGRATION_1_2 ,MIGRATION_2_3)
            .disableMigrationsChecking()
            .build();

    ReActiveAndroid.init(new ReActiveConfig.Builder(this)
            .addDatabaseConfigs(appDatabaseConfig)
            .build());


}
```

}

---

ALTER TABLE Note ADD COLUMN nameid INTEGER;

Comment: Never used ReActive android database, but are you sure file from_2_to_3.sql exists?

Comment: s , this file only

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment

Comment: I saved the assets file . from_2_to_3.sql     ALTER TABLE Note ADD COLUMN nameid INTEGER;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write DDL Queries in `migrate()` as below.

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // if you need to create new table
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE your_table "
            + " ADD COLUMN column_name DATATYPE");
    }
};
```

Comment: Your code has Create Table , how to add new coulmn exiting database.

Comment: you need to use alter in that case.

Comment: Getting  error : while compiling: ALTER TABLE Note  ADD COLUMN nameid INTEGER,          But i have a model class for Note  table.

Comment: @Table(name = "Notes", database = AppDatabase.class)
public class Note extends Model {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "nameid")
    private int nameid;

Comment: this the model class table name for Note , i added the new column nameid .

Comment: does it exist in your older version?

Comment: No sir, i change version number 3.

Comment: can you show what error you are getting after change.

Comment: how to add new column for exiting database model class

Comment: you can use above code to add the column, if it is showing you error please post it.

Comment: no such table: Note (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE Note  ADD COLUMN nameid INTEGER

Comment: there is a bug in room you need change room version to `1.1.1-rc1`

Comment: in your build.gradle you just need to set room version to 1.1.1-rc1

Comment: I have using this library file ,                                                                             compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5"

Comment: Working Your code, Thank you for your help. Thankq.